# Quarkus - Panache always use default data source and not the assigned DataSource

Tags: mysql, postgresql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to do a CRUD to two different data source (PostgreSQL and MySQL)
However, it seems even after assigning a `@DataSource` to the repository class, it still uses the default one.

This is the error I got:

```
2023-10-27 17:54:28,443 ERROR [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate post-boot validation thread for <default>) Failed to validate Schema: Schema-validation: missing table [cash_postgres]
```

I assume Quarkus is using the default data source is because `cash_postgres` did not exist in the MySQL db and only in my PostgreSQL.

I've tried to follow [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#configure-multiple-datasources) documentation, and other StackOverflow/Github questions/ticket but still have no clue.

This is my `application.properties`

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mysqldb

quarkus.datasource."mysqldatasource".db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource."mysqldatasource".username=root
quarkus.datasource."mysqldatasource".jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mysqldb

quarkus.datasource."postgresqldatasource".db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource."postgresqldatasource".username=user
quarkus.datasource."postgresqldatasource".password=password
quarkus.datasource."postgresqldatasource".jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/postgresdb

quarkus.http.port=8080
```

This is my Entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cash_mysql")
public class CashMySQL {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cash_postgres")
public class CashPostgres {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

This is my repo

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@DataSource("mysqldatasource")
public class CashMySQLRepository implements PanacheRepository<CashMySQL> {}

@ApplicationScoped
@DataSource("postgresqldatasource")
public class CashPostgresRepository implements PanacheRepository<CashPostgres> {}
```

This is my resource

```java
@Path("/benchmark")
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    @DataSource("mysqldatasource")
    CashMySQLRepository cashMySQLRepository;
    @Inject
    @DataSource("postgresqldatasource")
    CashPostgresRepository cashPostgresRepository;
}
```

Really appreciate any help I can get

Comment: IIRC, you need to set up the persistence units, and assign the packages to different persistence units. See [the official guide (`quarkus.io`)](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm) for details.

Answer (score 1):

What we need to do is

- create two persistence units, one for mySql, one for Postgres,
- move the two `Entity` classes in separate packages,
- bind the mySql persistence unit to the mySql data source
- bind the package with the mySql `Entity` to the mySql persistence unit
- bind the postgres persistence unit to the mySql data source
- bind the package with the mySql `Entity` to the postgres persistence unit.

When we asusme that class `CashMySQL` lives in package `de.turing85.persistence.entity.mysql` and class `CashPostgres` lives in package `de.turing85.persistence.entity.postgres`, the `application.properties` could look like this:

```
quarkus.datasource."mysqldatasource".db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource."postgresqldatasource".db-kind=postgresql

quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".datasource=mysqldatasource
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".packages=de.turing85.persistence.entity.mysql

quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".datasource=postgresqldatasource
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".packages=de.turing85.persistence.entity.postgres
```

With a corresponding implementation for our endpoint:

```
@Path("cash")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CashEndpoint {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  private final CashMySQLRepository mySqlRepository;
  private final CashPostgresRepository postgresRepository;

  public CashEndpoint(@DataSource("mysqldatasource") CashMySQLRepository mySqlRepository,
      @DataSource("postgresqldatasource") CashPostgresRepository postgresRepository) {
    this.mySqlRepository = mySqlRepository;
    this.postgresRepository = postgresRepository;
  }


  @POST
  @Transactional
  public int[] generateRandomEntry() {
    Date now = new Date();
    int amount = RANDOM.nextInt(1000);
    String createdBy = "foo" + RANDOM.nextInt();
    String updatedBy = "bar" + RANDOM.nextInt();
    // @formatter:off
    CashMySQL cashMySQL = CashMySQL.builder()
        .amount(amount)
        .createdBy(createdBy)
        .updatedBy(updatedBy)
        .createTime(now)
        .updateTime(now)
        .build();
    // @formatter:on
    mySqlRepository.persist(cashMySQL);

    // @formatter:off
    CashPostgres cashPostgres = CashPostgres.builder()
        .amount(amount)
        .createdBy(createdBy)
        .updatedBy(updatedBy)
        .createTime(now)
        .updateTime(now)
        .build();
    // @formatter:on
    postgresRepository.persist(cashPostgres);
    return new int[] {cashMySQL.getId(), cashPostgres.getId()};
  }

  @GET
  @Path("mysql/{id}")
  public CashMySQL getFromMySqlById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return mySqlRepository.findById(id);
  }

  @GET
  @Path("postgres/{id}")
  public CashPostgres getFromPostgresById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return postgresRepository.findById(id);
  }
}
```

and a happy path test:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(CashEndpoint.class)
class CashEndpointTest {

  @Inject
  @DataSource("mysqldatasource")
  CashMySQLRepository mySqlRepository;

  @Inject
  @DataSource("postgresqldatasource")
  CashPostgresRepository postgresRepository;

  @Test
  void testPostAndGet() {
    // @formatter:off
    long[] ids = RestAssured
        .when().post()
        .then()
            .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
            .extract().body().as(long[].class);

    CashMySQL cashMySqlFromHttp = RestAssured
        .when().get("/mysql/%d".formatted(ids[0]))
        .then()
            .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
            .extract().body().as(CashMySQL.class);
    // @formatter:on
    CashMySQL cashMySqlFromDb = mySqlRepository.findById(ids[0]);
    assertThat(cashMySqlFromHttp).isEqualTo(cashMySqlFromDb);

    // @formatter:off
    CashPostgres cashPostgresFromHttp = RestAssured
        .when().get("/postgres/%d".formatted(ids[0]))
        .then()
            .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
            .extract().body().as(CashPostgres.class);
    // @formatter:on
    CashPostgres cashPostgresFromDb = postgresRepository.findById(ids[0]);
    assertThat(cashPostgresFromHttp).isEqualTo(cashPostgresFromDb);
  }
}
```

we can validate the behaviour.

A full example can be found in [this `github.com` repository](https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-multi-pu).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to run your code but removing the `.database.generation=drop-and-create` to ensure it doesn't just create a new table. But it seems somehow your code cannot connect to the MySQL db. I got this error `Failed to validate Schema: Schema-validation: missing table [cash_mysql]`

Comment: Please read the message you posted carefully. The application can connect to the database, but the table `cash_mysql` is missing. Since the ddl is not created automatically, we have to provide it somehow.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I already have `cash_mysql` table created previously. So I assume the `drop-and-create` is not needed. I've also tried to run your code without any modification. But when generate the data, no new entries were put into MySQL table

Comment: So I tried to run your code again, and removing all the postgres part. It still runs but somehow the data in MySQL table is not updated accordingly...

Comment: I suspect you have configured the database connections? Otherwise, a corresponding container (mysql/postgres) will be started by quarkus, i.e. the databases are then containerized, and the corresponding configuration is injected into the application.

Comment: hmm yes I configured them (add username/password/url) to use my existing DB. my existing DB are using docker. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mysqldb and jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/postgresdb